# Why my code not working in formating while creating 2x3 matrix using if else condtion

Tags: python

Code.just trying to create a 2x3 matrix using if else condtion

```
list_=[' 'for i in range(1,9)]
for i in list_:
    c=1
    if c<4:   
        #row1='|{}|'.format(i)
        row1='| |'* c
        print (row1)
        c=c+1

    elif c<7:
        row2='|{}|'.format(i)
        print (row2)
        c=c+1
```

Expected out

```
| | | |
| | | |
```

Comment: what is the current output?

Comment: | | 6 times as column

Comment: Put that in your question.

Comment: Why the range is from 1 to 9?

Comment: You're resetting the variable `c` on each step of the loop, so the `elif` will never run. But more importantly, could you explain what you're trying to accomplish? It isn't clear why you wouldn't just print the expected output and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this code:

```
c=1
row='| |'
for i in range(1, 5):
    if c==1:   
        print (row, end = ' ')
        c=c+1
    elif c==2:
        print (row)
        c=c+1
    elif c==3:
        print (row, end = ' ')
        c=c+1
    elif c==4:
        print (row)
```

Output is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly but still there are some other smart ways to achieve the same output, although it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

```
list_=['x' for i in range(1,9)]
c=1
for i in list_:
    # print(f'c {c}')
    if c<4:
        # row1='| |'* c
        row1='|{}|'.format(i)
        print(row1,end='')
        c=c+1
        # print('if')
    elif c==4:
        print()
        c=c+1
    elif c<8:
        # print('elif')
        row2='|{}|'.format(i)
        print(row2,end='')
        c=c+1
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below:
Note:Python (v2.7.13)

```
for i in range(8):
    if i==3:
        print '|'
    else:
        print '|',
```